# Help! cec-ctl and vlc fullscreen seems to be mutually exclusive

Tags: vlc, raspberry-pi-desktop, cvlc

Is it possible for cec-ctl (NOT cec-client) to work with VLC fullscreen (vlc --fullscreen) from the CLI?
**NOTE:** I am ***not*** interested in running VLC from the Desktop.  In my case, VLC is started by streamlink and works great with cec-client. BUT, cec-client is a segmentation fault generating machine, buggy, unstable, unsupported hack and I cannot trust it at all for this project. cec-ctl has never crashed in all my testing/development but, as noted below, there are other show-stoppers...
 
I am using Raspberry Pi 3 B+, Raspbian 9, 10, or 11. I have tried Googling this for weeks and have tried the following two configs (along with many, many other permutations):
In the /boot/config.txt file:
**dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d** and **vlc --fullscreen**, results-> Full Screen fuzzy, intermittent video, Audio Works, NO CEC.
**dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d** and **vlc --fullscreen**, results-> Full Screen BLACK only, NO Audio, CEC WORKS great.
I don't have enough reputation to add tags: cec-ctl
The dtoverlay kms/fkms settings cause cec-ctl and vlc FULLSCREEN functionality to be mutually exclusive, in my case.  What am I doing wrong?  Is this even possible? 
Any constructive guidance on this topic will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not running Raspbian (which is effectively meaningless). Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye has new firmware supporting KMS. raspberry-pi-desktop is an OS for PC not Pi. Pick ONE and be consistent.

Comment: @Milliways: Thank you for your comment.  If you referring to the TAG attached to this question, please know that it is in error according to your comment.  I attached the tag naively thinking I was communicating that I have tried Raspbian OS 9, 10, and 11 Desktop versions.  But, now I am wondering, after reading your comment, do I need a Raspberry Pi 4 to use cec-ctl with vlc fullscreen together?